# no viable overloaded '=' error C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store the proper ticket variable (either t1 or t2) into t3 so I can return that to the main. When I use "=" to set either t1 to t3, it says "no viable overloaded '='". The following is my code:

```
using namespace std;

class ticket
{
public:
    ticket();
    double input();
    double output();
    friend ticket operator *(const ticket &t1, const ticket &t2);
    friend ticket operator /(const ticket &t1, const ticket &t2);
private:
    void cost();
    string name;
    double miles, price;
    int transfers;
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* error output, in full, unedited and with any informational notes (GCC/Clang should give some, showing what you have and what it expected). Also show the code that causes the error, including declarations/definitions and initializations of all involved variables.

Comment: Reduce the problem to a **minimum but complete** example that readers can try out. By the way, (1) you really don't need to reflect the structure of UTF-8 encoding in your `character` type, that's needless complexity, and (2) just use a `std::vector` to manage the storage. Or, (3) easy way out, define `enum character: Byte {}`, define a `char_traits`, and use a `std::basic_string` specialization.

Comment: `struct character` is not the best way to do whatever you're trying to do.  Actually this will lead to undefined behaviour in Standard C++  (you may only read the same member of a union as you last wrote - you can't write one member and read another, or cast some data to the union type).  Even if using a union aliasing compiler extension, you can't rely on the order of bitfields.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c1` and the literal `'\0'` are of type `char`, not instances of the `character` structure.

The types `char` and `character` are totally unrelated and you can't simply convert between the two.

A simple solution is to create conversion constructors for the `character` structure, that accepts single `char` argument and properly initialize the structure with that character.

Or simply create a `character` structure and explicitly set the correct member to the character you want.

Comment: @hereToLearn There's really no easy way to convert a "string" of `character` structures to a C-style "string" using pointers, or the other way around. You have to create a function which allocates enough memory for the resulting array dynamically (using `new[]`) and then loop over the string and do the conversion  one character at a time.